# How to remove blank slide on different devices on flexslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have created a responsive slider using Flexslider for iPad and iPhone. My slider have different content on two device. Let say I have 1 slide on iPad and 2 slides on iPhone. I get a blank slides on iPad, Automatically. is there any magical way to remove the blank slide on iPad?

My css:

```
iPhone-only{display:none !important;}
iPad-only{display:none !important;}
@media (max-width: 320px){
iPhone-only{ display:block !important}
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px){
iPad-only{ display:block !important}
}
```

My Html:

```
 <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
         <li> <div class"iPad-only"> iPad Slide 1 </div> <div class"iPhone-only> iPhoneSlide1 </div </li>
         <li> <div class"iPhone-only"> iPhone slide 2 </div>  </li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Share screenshots. Without them, it will be difficult to imagine the view.

Comment: You are only hiding the content _inside_ the LI, but not the LI itself – so naturally you get an “empty” slide now, because the slides are created based on the list items. Try hiding the list item itself instead. If that doesn’t work either (don’t know if flexslider checks element visibility), then you might have to remove the LI element from the DOM before initializing the slider.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. 

@CBroe
I tried hiding the li but I get a small bug. Slides jump about 20px down. I suppose it has to do with flexslider css:
.flexslider .slides > li {
  display: none;
}

Do you have any suggestion for fixing that?

Comment: @CBroe, I am a newbie to css & html. can you please explain in depth "you might have to remove the LI element from the DOM before initializing the slider." 

One more thing hiding the whole LI element won't remove the whole slide. There are equal slides for both devices so I still get 2 slides on iPad which a duplication of first slide instead of blank

Comment: this response is late but thought it can help someone.  Flexslider is js based so when it initializes it chooses the images selected.  If you change them in the dom you would have to reinitialize the flexslider js.  You can 1. Set the css and then reinitialize it immediately after.